# Understanding of an adjustable capacitor

Tags: identification, components

I am just wondering about this component. It seems to be an adjustable capacitor. This PCB belongs to a Rogowski coil measurement device. I know this application has an integrator so I think this component is related to the integrator circuit and is adjustable for optimization.

Can anyone explain what the component shown in photo is? How can I determine its value so I can buy one?

[image]

Comment: That is indeed a variable capacitor. Regarding the question "How I can buy capacitor", you need to elaborate on that a bit. I could answer that question with "Go to some-electronics-shop.com and order one", but I guess that wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: It's an adjustable capacitor yes. It's 2 stacks of interleaved half plates. By rotating the stacks will overlap more or less, influencing capacitance.

Comment: It’s a Philips film dielectric trimmer cap. The color indicates the capacitance range which is 1.5 to 5pF methinks.

Answer (score 2):

Answering, your question...

Yes, it is an adjustable capacitor. Each capacitor 'plate' is usually a stack of vanes, with a gap between each vane. A vane looks like slightly less than half a disc, mounted on the central shaft. One 'plate' stack is fixed, the other is rotated by the adjustment shaft. This moves the stacks of vanes in between each other. The amount in which the stacks are overlapping in between each other produces the amount of capacitance.

No, I'm afraid the site cannot recommend a place to buy them as that is off-topic here. An Internet search should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's a miniature variable capacitor. It's a smaller version of the sort of tuning capacitor that used to be used in transistor radios. It will have a capacitance of a few picofarads.

To buy one, hunt through the web sites of reputable component suppliers.

Comment: They still use that kind of tuning in the cheapest portable radios.